# How can a Makefile determine the binary format the compiler will create?

Tags: gcc, makefile, executable, gnu-assembler

Is it possible for a Makefile to determine what binary format the compiler is targeting (i.e. PE, ELF, Mach-O, etc.)? Maybe by running the compiler or assembler with certain options?

Or can I accurately determine this from the OS (by running `uname -s` or something of the sort)?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal here?

Comment: @EtanReisner: To pass format information to the C preprocessor when compiling `.S` assembly files (that's a capital "S", indicating to `gcc` that the assembly file should be preprocessed).

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is why `configure` scripts exist -- that is, to probe the build environment to determine useful information that isn't directly available in the language.

I wouldn't be surprised if there is already an autoconf macro to handle this.  However, I didn't look.

The simplest way to accomplish what you want is to, first, compile the simplest possible program using the compiler and compiler options you want to test.  Then, use the `file` command to see what sort of file this created.  You can use `sed` or the like on the output to turn this into whatever symbol or string you want to pass to your real compilation.

If `file` is not to your taste, you could alternatively write a custom program to examine the output file to see what it is.